Design a efficent price notification system
I am trying to create a notification system where users can set

price point notification: user notified when price reach x$
change notification: notify the userswhen the price change every
x$

I am storing the user preferences in database and what is the efficent way to create the notify logic for these two feature.
I have thought using TreeMap for price point notification feature and setting fixed change rates for the change notification. That way we dont need to keep track of last notified price for each user.

Suppose the current price were 7 and a user wishes to be notified if and when the price reaches 8. The price goes to 9 and the user is notified. I assume that the notification request is then fulfilled and purged Also, I assume the price of the notification request can be below the current price. Correct?

Yes correct. Like ı write there is going to be 2 feature one is get notify every 10 $ change and notify whenever price reaches 300$.
